# BigQueryValueCheckOperator and standard sql

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I would like to know if there is a way to use standard sql with the airflow BigQueryValueCheckOperator in apache airflow 1.9 The airflow BigQueryOperator normally has a flag like this

`use_legacy_sql=False` to disable legacy sql. I can't find a way to achieve this with the BigQueryValueCheckOperator.

Rewriting the query in legacy sql is not an option for now since I want to use the `_PARTITIONTIME` in my where clause.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you put `#standardSQL` at the start of the query?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Unfortunately no because the BigQueryHook will set the use_legacy_sql flag to True by default which conflicts with the `#standardSql` 
 
Once this issue is fixed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1874 it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can't use **StandardSQL** with this operator.

However, for your use-case, you can still use `_PARTITIONTIME` with **Legacy Sql** as mentioned here in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_using_time_zones

Sample Query:

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  field1
FROM
  mydataset.partitioned_table
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2016-05-01")
  AND TIMESTAMP("2016-05-06")
  AND DATE_ADD([MY_TIMESTAMP_FIELD], 8, 'HOUR') BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2016-05-01 12:00:00")
  AND TIMESTAMP("2016-05-05 14:00:00");
```